# How to Update Envelope Custom Fields of Docusign Envelope In process, with rest API in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, docusignapi

I am trying to update a Custom field in a envelope that I have already sent.

Request URL: #https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/1976929/envelopes/21d46fc6-8bbe-4315-b606-47cfd0ee0e3c/custom_fields>

Request Body:

```
"{\"textCustomFields\": [{\"name\":\"customer_email\",\"value\":\"new_email@new.com\",\"show\":\"true\",\"required\":\"true\"}]}"
```

Response:

```
{"textCustomFields"=>
[{"fieldId"=>"10198325521", "name"=>"customer_email", "show"=>"true",
 "required"=>"true", "value"=>"new_email@new.com", 
"errorDetails"=>
{"errorCode"=>"CUSTOM_FIELD_ALREADY_EXISTS", "message"=>"Field Name:
 customer_email"}}], "listCustomFields"=>[]}
```

- I am trying to update the value of custom field 'Customer Email'
- the response I get is Custom Field Already exist.
- The use case if that if by mistake the envelope has been sent to wrong email, we'd like to update the already sent envelope with this new email and resend it.

I am on Ruby on Rails.

If initially I sent the envelope with a custom text field value old_email@email.com.
Now I would like to see the value changed to new_email@email.com

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a PUT or a POST?  Should be a PUT.

Also, you only need to specify "FieldId", "name", and "value".

```
{
  "textCustomFields": [{
    "fieldId": "10210399758",
    "name": "customer_email",
    "value": "new_email@new.com"
  }]
}
```